# HTTPWebRequest File Uploading from memory

Tags: php, vb.net

I want to send data to my web server from my windows application.
Firstly i was sending data with URL parameters but due to URL lenght limit it was failing with large data. Then i tried to send data like file uploads but my data is not a file. It is very long string(about 4k chars).
So file upload tutorials on internet i replaced FileStream with my byte array but on server side `$_FILES` variable is an empty array.
Here is my code.

```
Sub sendData(ByVal data As String)

    Dim enc_data As String = EncryptRJ256(data)
    Dim byteData() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(enc_data)

    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com")
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = True
    postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()


    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
    postresponse = postReq.GetResponse()
    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\kenar\Desktop\response.txt", thepage)
End Sub
```

There is nothing to show on server side. I'm using apache web server and checking `$_FILES` variable on PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you're uploading a file, I suggest trying to check your $_POST instead for data, as i'm guessing before you was checking $_GET. If you want to submit as a file you would have to set the appropriate content type as well.